# How to add button with only events using fullcalendar react?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am working on the react js project and created a calender with [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) and now I need to add a button with the already added events to add more events on same date. On click of the button I will open a popup and add new event on the selected date. how can I achive this?

```
<FullCalendar
   plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
   headerToolbar={{
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
   }}
   initialView='dayGridMonth'
   editable={true}
   selectable={true}
   selectMirror={true}
   eventAdd={(e) => console.log(e)}
   eventContent={renderEventContent}
   dayMaxEvents={true}
   weekends={true}
   initialEvents={this.state.list}
   select={this.dateSelectHandle}
/>
```

One more thing I have tried with `eventContent` but its added button according to events If two events are added on the same date the it shows to buttons.

```
function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
  return (
    <>
         <button>+ Add New</button>
         <div>{eventInfo.timeText}</div>
         <div>{eventInfo.event.title}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks probably makes more sense if you meant to add only one button per day, instead of one button per event

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @ADyson but now in day cell hook how can I check is there any event on that day?

Comment: any update @ADyson ?

Comment: No you can't know that except by running getEvents and filtering them by date. The day hook doesn't tell you that, directly, in fact since event loading is asynchronous, events might not even be loaded yet when the day cell is rendered

Comment: @ADyson so how can I add a button in day cell on basis of events on that day?

Comment: My previous comment explains why that isn't possible, or at least would be very unreliable. Was there something you didn't understand in what I wrote?